# Should it be <<extend>> or <<include>>? UML - Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml, crud, use-case

I am doing Use Case for CRUD application. I would like to understand the difference between extend and include. I think I got it right with the 'Search Booking' part. But I am not sure about connecting and disconnecting from the server. Could you please have a look and let me know if my Use Case is correct?

[image: Use Case]

Comment: `Disconnect from server` is no use case. `Connect to server` most likely neither.

Comment: Even if there is a button in a gui? So the user can do it?

Comment: Yes. Where is the added value? It's a (required) action in one of the UCs activities. Just like the dreaded "Login"-